# getting files form phone memory along with sd card files

Tags: android

i want to get internal phone storage files along with sdcard files ... but i am not getting any method to do this this is my code to get directory for external storage

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

and this is the function

```
private void getAllFilesOfDir(File directory) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Directory: " + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");

            final File[] files = directory.listFiles();

            if ( files != null ) {
                for ( File file : files ) {
                    if ( file != null ) {
                        if  (file.isDirectory() ) {  // it is a folder...
                            getAllFilesOfDir(file);
                        }
                        else {  // it is a file...
                             myList.add( file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

but i want to get files form phone storage any help please????

Comment: Many of the files and directories of the internal storage are restricted to access only by system components or the other apps owning them.  Even some files which are themselves readable sit below directories such as /data which are not listable, frustrating your tree expansion.

Comment: but suppose i want to access the images which are taken from camera.. or a pdf file etc.....

Comment: if it does not allow access but still there should be function which i dont khow which could allow us to access some of them....

Comment: Those would typically not be on the internal storage, but rather on the "External Storage" (even if, as is normal today, that is permanently installed).  For the files which are private, no, you can't (depending on the mode bits) list and/or read them - that's the whole point of them being non-public.

Comment: suppose i removed my sd-card now images left in gallery are only those which are form phone memory.. i cant view them????

Comment: That depends what you mean by "internal memory"  On Android, "Internal Storage" refers to the unix-style filesystem used to store system components, apps and their private data.  "External Storage" refers to a more primitive filesystem originally intended for images, downloads, and shared data - once upon a time this was a removable SD card, but today it is typically a permanent part of the phone.  Some recent phones also have a removable SD card, distinct from the "External Storage" which they handle in various ways.  There are already questions here on detecting the mountpoint of that.

Comment: but if external storage includes the type of files which i am asking then why i am not getting them on running this code of mine :(

Comment: What code?  The snippets you have posted will not work together without something else in between.  Also you might want to get a file manager app and do some manual exploring with that, to get an idea of what you should (and shouldn't) be able to see.

Comment: this code works i did not added all the code only necessary portion was added my bad :( thanku for your concern and time:)

Comment: private File directory=new File( root) ; this is between the above two codes

Comment: So what output do you obtain?  You don't recursively descend the tree, so you'll probably not see the actual image files, but if you don't have any bugs you might find the directory containing them.

Comment: yup i get directory and name of the files along their path... they are like /mnt/sdcard/...... my point is why  /mnt/sdcard/ only i save files some time in phone memory why i cant get them...... now when i remove card ..i have images in gallery but on running my app i am not getting any thing..

Answer (score 0):

For check whether , the device has internal storage, external storage or both, use this:

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
    mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
} else {
    mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
}

if (mExternalStorageAvailable) {
    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .getAbsolutePath()
                         + "/EMD Systems/Append");
    if (!path.exists()) {
        path.mkdirs();
    }
    f = path;
} else {
    File dir1 = getApplicationContext().getDir("EMD Systems", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File dir = new File(dir1 + "/Append");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    f = dir;
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question asked.

Comment: sorry , above i didn't mention how to get file from internal(phone) storage or external storage pls do this" File[] files = f.listFiles(); " to list out file